# PERL: Jumping to lines in a huge text file

Tags: perl, bigdata

I have a very large text file (~4 GB).
It has the following structure:

```
S=1
3 lines of metadata of block where S=1
a number of lines of data of this block
S=2
3 lines of metadata of block where S=2
a number of lines of data of this block
S=4
3 lines of metadata of block where S=4
a number of lines of data of this block
etc.
```

I am writing a PERL program that read in another file,
foreach line of that file (where it must contain a number),
search the huge file for a S-value of that number minus 1,
and then analyze the lines of data of the block belongs to that S-value.

The problem is, the text file is HUGE, so processing each line with a

```
foreach $line {...} loop
```

is very slow. As the S=value is strictly increasing, are there any methods to jump to a particular line of the required S-value?

Comment: Try `while` instead. If this is a no go, read certain size of MB into buffer and count  newlines in order to locate desired line.

Comment: Is number of BYTES in each record the same?

Comment: Do you need to find a lot of those S values (to analyze their text) in a file, or not so many?

Comment: You could create an index on that file with S-value/filepos, look up (binary search) the value in the index and then seek() to that fileposition. Without an index you could do some sort of binary search in the file directly - i.e. seek() to halfway of the file, scan for the first S from that pos, and keep repeating until you reach S. This would need multiple file reads (log n) while using an index would only need one read into the big file. Both solutions would hardly use any memory for the big file (only the size of the index in the first solution, none at all in the second).

Comment: Does the file change? If not, convert it to a better format.

Comment: Are the S values sorted? If so, you could use a binary search

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *are there any methods to jump to a particular line of the required S-value?*

Yes, if the file does not change then create an index. This requires reading the file in its entirety once and noting the positions of all the `S=#` lines using [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html). [Store it in a DBM file](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html) with the key being the number and the value being the byte position in the file. Then you can use [`seek` to jump to that point in the file and read from there](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html).

But if you're going to do that, you're better off exporting the data into a proper database such as [SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite). Write a program to insert the data into the database and add normal SQL indexes. This will probably be simpler than writing the index. Then you can query the data efficiently using normal SQL, and make complex queries. If the file change you can either redo the export, or use the normal `insert` and `update` SQL to update the database. And it will be easy for anyone who knows SQL to work with, as opposed to a bunch of custom indexing and search code.

Answer (score 2):

If the blocks of text are of the same length (in bytes or characters) you can calculate the position of the needed S-value in the file and `seek` there, then read. Otherwise, in principle you need to read lines to find the S value.

However, if there are only a few S-values to find you can estimate the needed position and [seek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) there, then [read](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) enough to capture an S-value. Then analyze what you read to see how far off you are, and either `seek` again or read lines with `<>` to get to the S-value.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Fcntl qw(:seek);

my ($file, $s_target) = @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not $file or not -f $file;
$s_target //= 5;  #/ default, S=5

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; 

my $est_text_len = 1024;
my $jump_by      = $est_text_len * $s_target;  # to seek forward in file

my ($buff, $found);

seek $fh, $jump_by, SEEK_CUR;  # get in the vicinity

while (1) {

    my $rd = read $fh, $buff, $est_text_len;
    warn "error reading: $!" if not defined $rd;
    last if $rd == 0;

    while ($buff =~ /S=([0-9]+)/g) {
        my $s_val = $1;

        # Analyze $s_val and $buff:
        # (1) if overshot $s_target adjust $jump_by and seek back
        # (2) if in front of $s_target read with <> to get to it
        # (3) if $s_target is in $buff extract needed text

        if ($s_val == $s_target) {
            say "--> Found S=$s_val at pos ", pos $buff, " in buffer";
            seek $fh, - $est_text_len + pos($buff) + 1, SEEK_CUR;
            while (<$fh>) {
                last if /S=[0-9]+/;  # next block
                print $_;
            }
            $found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }   
    last if $found;
}
```

Tested with your sample, enlarged and cleaned up (change `S=n` in text as it is the same as the condition!), with `$est_text_len` and `$jump_by` set at 100 and 20.

This is a sketch.  A full implementation needs to negotiate over and under seeking as outlined in comments in code. If text-block sizes don't vary much it can get in front of the needed S-value in two seek-and-reads, and then read with `<>` or use regex as in the example.

Some comments

- The "analysis" sketched above need be done carefully. For one, a buffer may contain multiple S-value lines. Also, note that the code keeps reading if an S-value isn't in buffer.
- Once you are close enough and in front of `$s_target` read lines by `<>` to get to it.
- The `read` may not get as much as requested so you should really put that in a loop.  There are recent posts with that.
- Change to [sysread](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) from `read` for efficiency. In that case use [sysseek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysseek.html), and don't mix with `<>` (which is buffered).
- The code above presumes one S-value to find; adjust for more. It absolutely assumes that S-values are sorted.

This is clearly far more complex than reading lines but it does run much faster, with a very large file and only a few S-values to find. If there are many values then this may not help.

---

The `foreach (<$fh>)`, indicated in the question, would  cause the whole file to be read first (to build the list for `foreach` to go through); use `while (<$fh>)` instead.

---

If the file doesn't change (or the same file need be searched many times) you can first process it once to build an index of exact positions of S-values. Thanks to [Danny_ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5708620/danny-ds) for a comment.

Comment: +1 - A second example/answer creating and using an index (S-value/filepos) would be great too. (I don't know Perl, so I can't provide the code). The index could be created once and stored on disk for as long as the file doesn't change. And since S is already in order, creating that index would be easy (just keep adding S-value/filepos). Then just binary search the smaller index in memory.

Comment: @Danny_ds Indeed. I presumed that it's (a small number of queries with) a new file every time. Added a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I know the op has already accepted an answer, but a method that's served me well is to slurp the file into an array, based on changing the "record separator" ($/).

If you do something like this (not tested, but this should be close):

```
$/ = "S=";
my @records=<fh>;
print $records[4];
```

The output should be the entire fifth record (the array starts at 0, but your data starts at 1), starting with the record number (5) on a line by itself (you might need to strip that out later), following by all the remaining lines in that record.

It's very simple and fast, although it is a memory pig...

Answer (score 1):

Binary search of a sorted list is an O(log N) operation. Something like this using `seek`:

```
open my $fh, '>>+', $big_file;
$target = 123_456_789;

$low = 0;
$high = -s $big_file;

while ($high - $low > 0.01 * -s $big_file) {
    $mid = ($low + $high) / 2;
    seek $fh, $mid, 0;
    while (<$fh>) {
        if (/^S=(\d+)/) {
            if ($1 < $target) { $low = $mid; }
            else              { $high = $mid }
            last;
        }
    }
}

seek $fh, $low, 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    # now you are searching through the 1% of the file that contains
    # your target S
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers in the second file. Now you can proceed thru the huge file in order, processing each S-value as needed.